# $(x-y)⋅(y-z)=0$ using dot product

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

How would I go about doing this?

**Background:**

For $(x−y)⋅(y−z)=0$, the vectors $x−y, y−z, x−z$ create a right-angled triangle, with the hypotenuse being $x−z$. I've solved this bit:
\begin{align}
\|x−y+y−z\|^2
&=\langle x−y+y+z,x−y+y+z\rangle  \\
&=\langle x−y,x−y>+\langle x−y,y−z\rangle +\langle y−z,z−y\rangle +\langle y−z,y−z\rangle  \\
&=\|x−y\|^2+\|y−z\|^2,
\end{align}
but I need to prove $(x-y)⋅(y-z)=0$ using dot product, which has me stuck.
So far, I have $(x−y)⋅v$, but unsure how to proceed from here. What would the next step be?

Comment: Isn't that provided as the hypothesis? Could you please state your question more clearly? This helps to get more answers.

Comment: The simplest method would be to just check if Pythagoras theorem is being satisfied.